# error while passing the date value in the URL

Tags: javascript, java, html

I want to pass the value which is of date format through the URL to the java controller, but it's throwing javascript errors near the date.

My URL is as below:

```
var dataUrl = myAppURL+'/detailData/'+adviceNum+'/'+dateCreated +'/myDetailData.form';
```

Below code is how i'm getting the date value.

```
                    dateCreated = new Date(value.dateCreated);
                    var dd = dateString.getDate();
                    var mm = dateString.getMonth()+1;
                    var yyyy = dateString.getFullYear();
                    if(dd<10) {
                        dd='0'+dd
                    }
                    if(mm<10) {
                        mm='0'+mm
                    }
                    dateCreated = yyyy + '-' + mm+'-'+dd;
```

dateCreated has the value `2015-01-20.`

Error :
Failed to load the resource: the server : `8080/detailData/23/detailData/myDetailData.form responded with status of 404.`
Please advice how can i pass the dateCreated value to java controller.

Answer (score 0):

Is "dateString" supposed to be "dateCreated"?

This code works:

```
var dateCreated = new Date('2015-01-20');
var dd = dateCreated.getDate();
var mm = dateCreated.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = dateCreated.getFullYear();
if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
}
if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
}
dateCreated = yyyy + '-' + mm+'-'+dd;
;
console.log(dateCreated, typeof(dateCreated));
```

*2015-01-20 string*